Send email from nodemailer to outlook to be part of a conversation
I have smtp and imap set up on a email address and I can see all the emails inside the inbox and with the microsoft graph api I can get the emailId and I can see that I have also a parentFolderId and a conversationId, when I reply to these emails in outlook they become a conversation but when I use the smtp and send the email it creates a new email.
Replied emails when written in outlook become part of a conversation and have the same parentFolderId and conversationId
The smtp client I am using is nodemailer and here is the code, it sends the email but its just not part of the conversation, how can I make this email part of a conversation to outlook
  mailOptions2={
    from: "myemail@myemail.co.uk",
    to : "myemail@myemail.co.uk",
    subject : strSubject,
    html : body.value.messages[0].text.body,
    inReplyTo : myMessages[0].id,
    parentFolderId : myMessages[0].parentFolderId,
    conversationId : myMessages[0].conversationId,
    headers: {
      "inReplyTo" : myMessages[0].id
    }
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions2, function(error, response)
  {
    if(error)
    {
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      res.end("sent");
    }
  });

